# Is "Who do you think are the most superstitious people in the world?" really grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

I just wonder why

> Who do you think are the most superstitious people in the world?

is grammatical, according to the answers in the back of my book.

Please, can you tell me why? Shouldn't it be

> Who do you think the most superstitious people are in the world?

Comment: Which aspect of the quoted text are you having difficulty with? Also, when you say it's right, right in what context?

Comment: The context is 'who do you think are the most superstitous people in the world?' And I get confused in 'are' part.

Comment: Do you mean why "are" rather than "is"? That is, do you mean subject-object number agreement?

Comment: I mean the position of are, why shouldn't it be 'who do you think the most superstitius people are in the world?'.I'm really sorry for bothering you.

Comment: "Who are the most superstitious people in the world?" is the basic question. "Do you think" is just a phrase inserted to indicate that you are asking for someone's personal opinion.

Comment: Siranush, **a**, kindly look at the corrections and changes to your question above. *Those* grammatical problems are more important than the one you're asking about. *In the back* or *at the end* when you're talking about the last part of a book.

Comment: **b** You're not wrong to be a little confused. The grammar can work with the verb in either place, with very little change in meaning. The modifier *in the world* is better off staying closer to *people*, though: Who do you think the most X people in the world are?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying me and yes you're right.I agree with you.I wrote every word without even looking at.I'm so sorry for that.

Comment: @SiranushA *Clarifying that* or *butter*, but not people. Add spaces after your periods. *Looking at* needs an object (*it*). It's ok and we don't look carefully at everything either. As you learn, though, it helps to pay more attention or phrase things more simply at first, until you're doing well enough without being careful to move on to the harder bits.

Comment: ell.stackexchange.com is also better and more welcoming for basic grammar questions.

Comment: Illy is right, although I'd say 'Who do you think the most superstitious people are in the world?' is non-standard. Keep the PP near 'people'.

Answer (score 3):

> - *Who do you think **are** the most superstitious people in the world?*

is grammatical. And so is

- *Who do you think the most superstitious people in the world **are**?*

> But this one is ***not*** grammatical
>
> - **Who do you think the most superstitious people **are** in the world?*
>
> because the subject of the question is the entire noun phrase *the most superstitious people in the world*, and when you do subject-auxiliary inversion in forming the question, you have to move the auxiliary *are* **all** the way around that noun phrase, instead of dropping it in the middle, between *people* and *in*.

The reason why *are* is OK in both positions is because the complement clause is reversible.
Note the two original (pre-question) sentences:

- *You think (that) the most superstitious people in the world **are** `who`*.
- *You think (that) `who` **are** the most superstitious people in the world*.

Forming  Y/N questions (the first step in *Wh*-Question Formation) upstairs,
while leaving the *Wh*-word and auxiliary  in a different place downstairs in each one.

- *Do you think the most superstitious people in the world **are** `who`?*
- *Do you think `who` **are** the most superstitious people in the world?*

And now moving the *Wh*-words to the front of the sentence (the second part of *Wh*-Question Formation):

- *Who do you think the most superstitious people in the world **are**?*
- *Who do you think **are** the most superstitious people in the world?*

we wind up with the two simple ways to make a *Wh*-Question out of the original.

Comment: In the case of the split noun phrase, even if *in the world* cannot be part of the same phrase as *the most superstitious people*, would not another parsing of the sentence still be valid? (Suppose we replace the trailing *in the world* with *in your opinion*. I expect that you believe that this sentence is indeed grammatical.)

Answer (score 1):

It works both ways. That's because there is one group with one characteristic. And one way it says the characteristic belongs to the group, while the other way it says the group has the characteristic. It amounts to the same thing.

Start with a simple example. Instead of the complicated "most superstition people in the world" let's just put in "tallest." And instead of a bunch of people, let's just have John.

Consider this sentence.  John is the tallest.  That is, you've got the subject John. And the thing he is doing is being tallest.

Now think if it makes sense to rewrite that sentence as follows.  The tallest is John.  Yes, it makes sense. But now, the subject is "the tallest." This means there is a tallest person. And the thing he is doing is being John. It it nearly the same thing.  But it picks things out in the opposite order. You've got John being tallest. Or you've got the tallest person and he's being John.

Now add the question in there.

Who is the tallest? John is tallest.

The tallest is who? The tallest is John.

Either works.

Comment: In simplifying the question, you've removed part of the actual question OP is asking about – the positioning of the prepositional phrase relative to 'the most superstitious people'.